Image as plane imported turns the image grey and slightly blurry any idea how to make it look like the original?
I'm new to blender and found a similar problem with another person, but their question wasn't solved, essentially I import it from my file as a plane, and it becomes greyish and unlike its original form any clue how to fix?
Original picture:

this is how it looks like in Blender:


hello could you please pack your image and share your file?

i hope this helps

There are two things going on here:
Blur
By default, any image texture in the shader editor uses the Linear interpolation to hide the pixel edges of your texture. It looks better in most cases, but for a very low resolution image like yours it's maybe a bit too much.

You could set it to Closest, which is like having no interpolation, but then zooming into your picture or scaling it too much relative to the camera will let the pixels visible. But ideally, if you do not want to see pixels, you should just use higher resolution pictures and avoid this issue altogether.
Graying
The look of an image being the product of many things: the material in which it is, reflections, lighting, ...
So if you want your image to be rendered as is with no reflections or needing specific lighting, the first thing to do would be to make sure your image is using an emissive material, such as this:

Alternatively, when using the Import Image as Plane addon (or the menu Add > Image > Mesh Plane since version 4.2), in the file browsing dialogue you can change the Material import property from Principled to Emissive or Shadeless:

But one thing beginners often don't think of is the Color Management.
By default, Blender's Color Management is set to use the AGX view transform, which is better suited for rendering with photorealistic engines, but result in sRGB images to be displayed differently.
If you used a different startup template, such as 2D Animation, it will probably use "Standard":

Does no extra conversion besides the conversion for the display device. Often used for non-photorealistic results or video editing where a specific look is already baked into the input video.

Since version 4.2, we also have the Khronos PBR Neutral which can be used as a middle ground as it does an OK job at preserving imported images' sRGB colors but still allow some faithful color rendering like AGX or Filmic would and without burning things too quick like sRGB/Standard would.
